# HTTP requests stuck in Pending state when using Vite

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome, chromium, vite

I have a rather large Vue 3 application (~550 components). It takes two minutes just to run `vue-cli-service serve` and around 20 seconds to re-build it after each change. Hot reload stopped working a long time ago so it always needs to be refreshed in the browser even after a small style change. Moreover, the app is still not finished and it will probably get 2-3 times this big in the next year so it will probably be even worse.

Because of these problems, I've decided to migrate it from Vue CLI to Vite. I have already resolved a lot of problems and the app seems to work with Vite now with so much better loading times.

However, it sometimes gets stuck when I start a dev server (`vite` command) and open it in a browser. The page keeps loading and I can see a lot of pending requests in the Network tab of Chrome DevTools. There's nothing special in the output of `vite --debug` and running `vite --force` doesn't help either.

[image]

When this problem occurs, the browser always loads a lot of modules (~900) and then it gets stuck on 10-20 modules. The status of all these HTTP requests is simply `Pending` and they never finish. There are no errors in the browser or on the command line.

I don't think any particular file causes this. Maybe the problem is in my deeply nested folder structure with a lot of re-exports using `index.ts` file on each level. It mostly gets stuck on my own modules but I've also seen cases when it was waiting for a module of some external library.

Has anybody experienced a similar problem? How did you solve it?

**EDIT:** I have discovered that this issue only occurs in Chromium-based browsers (Google Chrome, Brave, etc.) on Linux. It works without any problems in Chrome on MacOS and Windows as well as in other browsers (Firefox, GNOME Web, etc.) on Linux.

Comment: Can you share a link to a reproduction?

Comment: I can't really share the source of code of this project. And I doubt I would be able to reproduce it if I created another project from scratch. But I can try.

Comment: I've realized that this issue only occurs in Chromium-based browser. My application works without any problems in Firefox. I was able to create a [reproducer](https://github.com/livthomas/vite-bugs/tree/main/pending-requests) and I also reported a [bug](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/5310) in Vite.

Comment: It's not reproducible in macOS. I see you're using Manjaro Linux, so it might be a problem only with Chromium-based browsers in that OS.

Comment: This is also reproducible on Ubuntu 21.04 (Chrome browser) if you try setting up https://github.com/directus/directus in your local

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to [this comment](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/5310#issuecomment-948649875), I realized this was a problem with the file descriptors limit.

On Manjaro Linux (Arch-based), I was able to solve it by adding the following line to both `/etc/systemd/system.conf` and `/etc/systemd/user.conf` file:

```
DefaultLimitNOFILE=65536
```

After this change, Vite works without any problems in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I'm using laravel with vite and I had the same issue multiple time, couldn't figure out why or how to fix. Which is frustrating spending so much time trying to figure out the issue, some times it works by it self after hours and I ignore the issue and continuo with developing the app.

Today, I might found that it's a network related issue or misconfiguration. Because as soon as I turned Airplane mode ON on `Windows 11`, turned it back off, it worked and everything loading fine as it supposed to.